# django-registation check user is active on template

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I tried to check in template that user who open activation link is already active or is there any else error. I tried in template user, user.is_active, user.is_authenticated, account but anything doesn't work or return False. How i could check it? I'm using Django 1.9 and django-registration

activation_complete.html

```
{% if account %}
  <p>Konto zostało pomyślnie aktywowane.</p>
  <p><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Zaloguj się.</a></p>
{% else %}
  <p>Aktywacja nie powiodła się. Proszę skontaktuj się z Administratorem.</p>
{% endif %}
```

It shows false but when I list user he's active:

```
users.get(username='test').is_active True
```

Comment: try `{% if request.user.is_active %}`

Comment: It doesnt't work it return False while it could be True

Comment: can you see in admin that user `is_active` and on site it returns false?

Comment: While I'm logged in it return True, but i need this to user activation. When user open activation link i need to check that this account is activated or I need to active account. When i click link `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/activate/InRlc3Qi:1atC7F:Uit44Uee7U7_czXuvb0YBYI0-T0/` i need to check that account is activated and i need to redirect or i need to active account it return false.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is work :

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    '<!-- show something -->'
{% else %}
    '<!-- dont show something -->'
{% endif %}
```